# How to make HTML page look like a pdf - same look no matter the screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I am building a single page site (let's say a copy of a brochure/magazine/resume). I made use of bootstrap's `container-fluid`.

The structure is somewhat -

```
body
 div - container-fluid
 div - container-fluid
   row
     col-7
     col-1
     col
```

with each column having several row containers.

What happens - When I reduce the screen size - the columns become stacked on top of one another.

What I want - When I reduce the screen size - everything reduces in size but the look should stay the same - just like viewing a pdf in mobile/laptop.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

add a CSS value to the div

```
display: flex
```